# Finding "which number is not" in a numeric sequence in R

Tags: r, sequence

When trying to exclude specific numbers from a sequence I have noticed that `which(!(0:10 %in% 2:3))` returns a different result (removes 3 and 4 and add 11) than `setdiff(0:10,2:3)` or `which(!(1:10 %in% 2:3))`.

```
which(!(1:10 %in% 2:3))
[1]  1  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
which(!(0:10 %in% 2:3))
[1]  1  2  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
setdiff(0:10,2:3)
[1]  0  1  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

This seems to be a simple logic problem but I can't figure what is this due to? Is `setdiff` as fast as `which(!())` for large sequences?

Comment: `which` gives you the position of the elements not the elements themselves

Comment: To make it clear try this example `which(!(10:20 %in% 12:13))`

Comment: It may be clearer if you omit the `which`: `0:10 %in% 2:3`. You'll see the first 2 elements (0, 1) are FALSE, the next 2 (2, 3) are TRUE, the remainder up to the 11th element (10) are FALSE.

Comment: Alright, I got it now thanks. So I need to do `myseq<-0:10`
`myseq[which(!(0:10 %in% 2:3))]`

Comment: As to which is faster (with data this size), `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(wh=which(!(0:10 %in% 2:3)), sd=setdiff(0:10,2:3))` says that `wh` has a median runtime of 2.7 microseconds and `sd` has a median runtime of 21.3 microseconds, so `wh` is almost 8 times faster. That's just one way of looking at it, but ... `which` wins out by far here.

Comment: `(0:10)[!0:10 %in% 2:3]` gives the same result as `setdiff` and, by very little, is faster than `which`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments, `which` gives the position of the elements, not the elements themselves, the example above is unclear but these examples make it obvious:

```
which(!(10:20 %in% 12:13))
[1]  1  2  5  6  7  8  9 10 11

0:10 %in% 2:3
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So the correct way of selecting the elements would be:

```
myseq<-0:10
myseq[which(!(0:10 %in% 2:3))]
```

Regarding speed, selecting the elements directly from the vector is slightly faster:

```
myseq<-0:1000000
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+   wh=myseq[which(!(0:1000000 %in% 2:3))],
+   sd=setdiff(0:1000000,2:3),
+   seq=(0:1000000)[!0:1000000 %in% 2:3]
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
   wh 18.62157 18.85489 25.17644 25.37830 26.89162 152.9487   100  a 
   sd 36.09655 42.83383 50.22088 44.16595 45.96227 178.2949   100   b
  seq 17.51332 17.98346 25.00993 24.39265 25.91137 174.1875   100  a
```

Comment: I wouldn't trust the microbenchmark results on an example this size. The difference of a few microseconds is too little to matter in almost any application. The methods may scale up differently to larger inputs. And to be a fair comparison you should benchmark expressions that give the same output, i.e., use `myseq[which(!(myseq %in% 2:3))]`.

Comment: For example, if I use `x = sample(1:1e6, size = 5e5);
y = sample(1:1e6, size = 1e5)` and benchmark `wh=x[which(!(x %in% y))],
  sd=setdiff(x, y)`, `which` is still faster, but it's about 30% faster, not 400% faster as in your small example.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have edited and used a larger vector, and used expressions that give the same output. The third option is still faster but not by much.

Comment: Much better. And thanks for providing an answer to your own question!